# При postback сервер не видит изменения, сделанные с помощью jQuery ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, разработчики! В asp.net я с помощью jQuery делаю ajax-запрос. Он отрабатывает, новые данные отображаются. Но когда я хочу сделать `postback`, то изменения, которые я сделал с помощью jQuery ajax, сервер не видит. В частности, я изменил с помощью jQuery выбранный элемент в `dropdownlist-е`, при `postback` вываливается `NullReferenceException` (нет выбранного элемента). Почему? И как сделать так, чтобы сервер при `postback` видел изменения, сделанные с помощью jQuery ajax? Ах, да... Код в студию! Это jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#DropDownList1").change(function (){
                var url = "Default.aspx #data2";
                $("#data2").load(
                url,
                {
                    "data1":$("#DropDownList1").val()
                });
            });
     });
    </script>
```

Это форма:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="data2">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            Text="PostBack" />
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
```

А это серверная часть:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Params["data1"] != null)
            {
                string s = Request.Params["data1"];
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    DropDownList2.Items.Add(s+i);
                }
                return;
            }
        }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text; //вот здесь NullReferenceException
    }
```

Comment: на что конкретно NullReferenceException?

Comment: Я могу достучатся до необходимых данных через Request.Param['mydata']. Но это не то. Уже другая логика завязана именно на значениях элементов управления. Переписывать не интересно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу предположить, происходит следущее:

1. При первой загрузке страницы контрол DropDownList2 пуст;
2. Выполняется ajax запрос с помощью [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Этот метод загружает целиком новую страницу, ищет в ней DropDownList2 (уже заполненный) и вставляет в старую, ничего более.
3. Т.к. DropDownList2 заполняется динамически, его содержимое сохраняется в ViewState. При ajax запросе ViewState текущей страницы не изменяется, т.е. по-прежнему содержит описание пустого DropDownList.
4. При postback'е на сервере содержимое контролов заполняется из ViewState, в котором для DropDownList2 - пусто.

Как вариант, можно на стороне сервера повторить логику заполнения контролов в точности, как на клиенте.

Comment: Да, скорее всего оно так. То есть вы хотите сказать, что при постбэке нужно пройти как бы все заново? Вызвать те же методы в том же порядке, что и при вызове ajax?

Comment: Или можно с помощью javascript внести изменения во viewstate

Comment: Что-то я не верю, что ViewState разумно редактировать из JavaScript. Нет гарантии, что ASP.NET всегда будет генерировать один и тот же формат ViewState, да и изменения на странице могут сломать привязку к ViewState.

Comment: Я тоже, как-то не решаюсь на это пойти. То есть сделать ajax запрос, а потом, если нужно отредактировать с помощью javascript ViewState, проще сразу вносить изменения из ajax запроса во ViewState, каким-либо образом.