# Жизненный цикл страницы при использовании jQuery ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Вопрос родился от [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/38140/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-postback-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-ajax). Каков жизненный цикл страницы при ajax запросe с помощью jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жизненный цикл тот же. Только на клиенте изменения происходят в том блоке, для которого вызывалась функция jQuery, например, load. Поэтому остальные части на странице клиента остались без изменения, в том числе среди которых может быть и ViewState.